# Python **kwargs and self as an argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, arguments, keyword-argument

I don't have much experience in python but I am studying `**kwargs`.

Afer reading a lot I understood somethings about `**kwargs` but I have a small problem **or** I am not understanding something correct.

So this **works**:

```
def test_var_kwargs(farg, **kwargs):
    print "formal arg:", farg
    for key in kwargs:
        print "another keyword arg: %s: %s" % (key, kwargs[key])

test_var_kwargs(farg=1, myarg2="two", myarg3=3)
```

And prints:

> formal arg: 1
>
> another keyword arg: myarg2: two
>
> another keyword arg: myarg3: 3

But if that function was an **instance function** then `self` would have to be included:

```
def test_var_kwargs(self, farg, **kwargs):
        print "formal arg:", farg
        for key in kwargs:
            print "another keyword arg: %s: %s" % (key, kwargs[key])
    
self.test_var_kwargs(farg=1, myarg2="two", myarg3=3)
```

But this produces an **error**:

```
TypeError: test_var_kwargs() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I understand that I have to pass self like:

```
self.test_var_kwargs(self, farg=1, myarg2="two", myarg3=3)
```

Why do I have to include self as an argument in the class instance's method?

Comment: Could you include the full code example of the **class function** example. I think you might be misunderstanding it.

Comment: no need to pass `frag=1`. Just pass it as `1`.

Comment: coz it counts `farg=1` as a keyword argument only.

Comment: @Wessie not misunderstanding classes. That is not the point

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use `farg` as keyword argument in that case; it cannot be interpreted as both a positional *and* a keyword argument, Python interprets it as a keyword argument in this case.

Use

```
self.test_var_kwargs(self, 1, myarg2="two", myarg3=3)
```

instead.

Functions act as descriptors; when looked up on an instance, they get wrapped in a new object called a method, which automatically adds the instance as a first argument to the function when called. This wrapper essentially does this:

```
class Method(object):
    def __init__(self, function, instance, cls):
        self.func = function
        self.instance = instance
        self.cls = cls

    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        return self.func(self.instance, *args, **kw)
```

Your `farg` keyword argument is then lumped under the `**kw` catchall and passed on to the underlying function, with `*args` left empty.

But the `test_var_kwargs` method you defined has one positional argument (next to `self`, and thus an exception is raised.

Comment: but why have I to include self on the arguments?

Comment: It doesn't appear to me that `farg` is interpreted as a positional and a keyword argument simultaneously. With proper class/object syntax, my machine produces the expected result.

Comment: You only need to include "self" for the definitions of instance methods. You NEVER have to include a reference to self when calling a method, that is done implicitly for you.

Comment: @KyleStrand: That was a mis-wording on my part, updated with the expanded answer.

Comment: Thanks. ouf at last. Thanks @ZoranPavlovic as well